# Remove hashtags with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a way to hide all hashtags on the page with javascript?

For instance, I have a tag cloud underneath each post on a website I'm making. Each tag looks something like: `#myhashtag`

I want javascript (possibly css?) to run through the document and hide the "#" so that the tag  ends up simply looking like: `myhashtag`

is this possible?

Comment: What are the tags? Are they links?

Comment: certainly is, although it would be a bit heavy on the dom, going through all the strings and removing the hashs

Comment: yeah, they are tags that are links.

Comment: so not recommended with javascript @JamieHutber ?

Comment: you need, document.innerText and a regex.

Comment: Ye, its the only way to do it @zer0ruth. Unless you can do it serverside, but seeing as you've tagged JS I imagine this is your only option ;) Depends how important it is to have and where you are using it. A normal site with no heavy JS sure, why not :)

Comment: I suppose using jQuery would make this a whole lot easier

Comment: try my answer, i tested it and it works to your questions standards without a loop or jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the hash tags be elements with a specific class. (Just edit the CSS selector accordingly if you have other identification marks.) Than 8 lines jQuery should do the trick:

```
  $('.my-hash-tag').each(function(i, elem) {
      var $elem = $(elem), text = $elem.text();

      if(text.length > 0 && text.charAt(0) == '#') {
         $elem.text(text.substring(1));
      }
  });
```

Comment: the OP isn't using jQuery... :/

Comment: this would require adding a class to every tag. would I be able to target each tag without adding a class? ie 
$('ul.tags li a').each(function(i, elem)) {

Comment: @JamieHutber - You could rewrite the code to use the querySelector, innerText and default DOM objects. Works the same is just a little bit more verbose.

Answer (score 1):

```
var doc = document.body;
doc.innerHTML = doc.innerHTML.replace(/(\B)#(\w+)\b/g, '$2');
```

Comment: -1 : completly ignoring possible hashes inside URLs and text which isn't a hash-tag.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job, comments explain how it works. Currently it assumes the tags are inside anchors and inside a div with id `#cloud` however this is easily edited, just use a different element selector the concept remains the same.

```
var tagCloud = document.getElementById("cloud"); // Get tag cloud element
var tags = tagCloud.getElementsByTagName('a'); // Find all anchors within cloud (If they aren't anchors change this to containing elements or replace with a class search .etc
for (var i=0, max=tags.length; i < max; i++) { // Loop through tags
     tags[i].innerHTML = tags[i].innerHTML.replace("#", ""); // Remove #'s
}
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3ayhA/1/